# how to apply CSS3 properties (i.e. -moz , -webkit border radius) to asp.net button & texbox control and to html fieldset & legend?

Tags: rounded-corners, css

I have applied rounded corners styles to my ASP.Net button & text box controls and also to fieldset and legend.

Here is my CSS-

```
fieldset
{
width:605px;
margin-bottom:20px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
}
fieldset legend
{
background: #606060 url(images/bluelines.gif) repeat-x center left;
 -moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
margin: 7px; 
padding: 10px 10px 0px 5px; 
}
fieldset legend:hover{
background: #606060 url(images/blue-lines.gif) repeat-x center left;
}
fieldset legend img
{
padding: 0px 6px 0px 0px; 
position: relative; 
bottom: 5px;
}
.txtBox 
{
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
height:15px; 
width: 200px;
padding: 5px;
background: #ffffff;   
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius:5px;   
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;

}
.txtBox:focus{
border: 2px solid #50cff1;
box-shadow: 5px 1px 1px 5px #000;

}
.buton{
background: #50cff1 url(images/nav-act.gif) repeat-x center left;
border: none;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.buton:hover
{color: #000000;}
```

Here is skin code-

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="txtBox" SkinID="textBox" />
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="buton" SkinID="button" />
```

But these styles aren't working in Internet Explorer(8,7,6). Please let me know any solution so that all of these styles will apply on these elements(asp.net button & textbox, fieldset & legend) in IE too!

Regards,
nzahra

Comment: Why would you expect Mozilla (`-moz-`) and WebKit (`-webkit-`) experimental properties to apply in IE?  Also, if you want people to answer your questions you should accept answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and below don't support CSS3, only IE9 does. To mimic CSS3, you'll need to use filters, .htc files (behaviors), images, or some combination thereof for any CSS3.

You can use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to hide the IE stuff from other browsers. [Here's some info on filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [one way of rounding corners in IE.](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser).